# ndk-build failed: No rule to make target pjsua_wrap.cpp needed by pjsua_wrap.o

Tags: android, bash, android-ndk, cygwin, pjsip

I have been trying to build the CSipSimple in my Win7 (X64) machine for couple of days.

I am using cygwin for building the code. But currently it is displaying me the below image.

[image]

Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: Have you set `NDK_PROJECT_PATH`?

Comment: NDK_PPROJECT_PATH? Where I have to set this ?

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful if you showed us your "android.mk" file. Here is an example of an android.mk file which builds a library called "mylib" from 2 cpp files:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

LOCAL_ARM_MODE :=arm

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := mylib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
          mysource1.cpp \
          mysource2.cpp \

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -lz -lm -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```